# htaccess 301 redirect not working

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6

I'm trying to redirect my old pages to new pages but this is not working. I've added these "redirects"  in the very beginning of the .htaccess file. When I added in the bottom, it gave server misconfiguration error. How to make it work?
Same would work in my Joomla based websites.
When I type "http://www.indiacustomercare.com/toll-free-customer-care-numbers-in-india.html" in Firefox it's giving error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>   Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.
>
> ```
> *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
> ```
>
> accept
>             cookies.

Here are the lines I've added in the very beginning of .htaccess

```
  redirect 301 /toll-free-customer-care-numbers-in-india.html http://www.indiacustomercare.com/toll-free-customer-care-numbers-india
    redirect 301 /vodafone-customer-care.html http://www.indiacustomercare.com/vodafone-customer-care-helpline-numbers
    redirect 301  /airtel-customer-care.html http://www.indiacustomercare.com/airtel-customer-care-contact-helpline-call-center-numbers
    redirect 301 /xmap-1.html   http://www.indiacustomercare.com/sitemap
    redirect 301 /index.html  http://www.indiacustomercare.com/reciprocal-link-exchange-add-your-url
```

Comment: This worked. I added this in the top of .htaccess

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$  http://www.indiacustomercare.com/reciprocal-link-exchange-add-your-url [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. I added this in the top of .htaccess

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.html$ indiacustomercare.com/reciprocal-link-exchange-add-your-url [R=301,L]
```